# Import from Excel to MySQL database using SQuirrel

Tags: sql, excel, import, squirrel-sql

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a few thousand entries in it. I want to import the table into a MySQL 4 database (that's what I'm given). I am using SQuirrel for GUI access to the database, which is being hosted remotely.

Is there a way to load the columns from the spreadsheet (which I can name according to the column names in the database table) to the database without copying the contents of a generated CSV file from that table? That is, can I run the LOAD command on a local file instructing it to load the contents into a remote database, and what are the possible performance implications of doing so?

Note, there is a auto-generated field in the table for assigning ids to new values, and I want to make sure that I don't override that id, since it is the primary key on the table (as well as other compound keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a few thousand entries in the spreadsheet then you shouldn't have performance problems (unless each row is very large of course).

You may have problems with some of the Excel data, e.g. currencies, best to try it and see what happens.

Re-reading your question, you will have to export the Excel into a text file which is stored locally. But there shouldn't be any problems loading a local file into a remote MySQL database. Not sure whether you can do this with Squirrel, you would need access to the MySQL command line to run the LOAD command.

The best way to do this would be to use Navicat if you have the budget to make a purchase?

Comment: Budget is minimal for this, and it's a one-off data synchronization issue. $140 is not bad for a piece of software, but not for a single use.

Squirrel does give a command line interface. Thanks for the warning about currencies, although the tables in question shouldn't have any such fields.

Comment: The other way to do this is to generate insert statements from the Excel spreadsheet using VBA, that is something that I've done and it works pretty well, I have a macro you could adapt if you interested, cheers, James

Comment: It looks like that's what I'm going to have to do, since the LOAD command does not seem to work properly. Oh well, I was hoping for a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I made [this tool where you can paste in the contents of an Excel file and it generates the  create table, and insert statements](http://utilitymill.com/utility/csv_to_create_table) which you can then just run.  (I'm assuming squirrel lets you run a SQL script?)

If you try it, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I can run scripts with SQuirrel, now I just have to wait until I get back to that project later today/tomorrow. I'll let you know.